# is there an asp.net fiddle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Similar to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), is there an asp.net fiddle website for us to share asp.net code fiddles? It'll greatly help asp.net developers. the current way to post asp.net code on SO is not so reader friendly. I hope there's something out there to make this easier. If there isn't anything like that (as i did some search but can't find one). Is this even something technically possible to be developed since c# is not a late binding language.

Comment: coderun.com lets you create asp.net code but its code editor is kind of jumpy. it's the only choice so far.

Comment: Yes there is http://www.dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: csharpfiddle.com is another option.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

<del>You could use something like compilr.com, however, it requires a paid account (as of June 2013) to create projects but people can view it anonymously. It's pretty neat.</del> (*compilr closed down*)

<del>Example:
http://compilr.com/cravecode/test-share/main.cs</del>

### <del>UPDATE 1</del>

<del>I'd also checkout [coderun.com/ide](http://www.coderun.com/ide/)</del> (no longer available)

### UPDATE 2

Check [dotnetfiddle.net](http://dotnetfiddle.net) which has Context menu as well (pointed out by @wulfbane).

### UPDATE 3 (2017-03-19)

Keeping answer updated, I now use:

- https://csharppad.com
- http://rextester.com **(has a really neat collaboration feature)**
- https://dotnetfiddle.net

You may also want to check [Ideone](http://ideone.com) (has no context menu)

Comment: Wonder if this is an example of Roselyn in action?

Comment: compilr.com offers these language choices (c, c#, c++, java, javascript, php, python, ruby and vb), but when i choose c# or vb, i can only do winform/console app. i hope it has asp.net web form and asp.net mvc.

Comment: http://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: @Wulfbane make it an answer so I can upvote you :)

Comment: Wish I could - this is closed

Comment: http://www.coderun.com/ide/ not working. 404 error.

Comment: Compilr is no longer as of July 31st 2015.

Comment: is there a local version of C# ASP fiddle?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net not working. 503 error. and https cert has expired on https://csharppad.com.

Comment: @BeaglesEnd, both look good now.

Comment: wondering if anywhere online to test a single aspx file with inline C#.net? too bad dotnetfiddle does not seem to offer it.