# Online CodeEditor with Intelligence (C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, ide

A Google search results in CodeMirrow. I could not find a c# demo and not sure if it support intelligence (or if thats even possible).

Does anyone know any (browser code editor) projects that support Intelligence/auto-completion. Im looking for a project that i can use freely on my own site.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873367/is-there-an-asp-net-fiddle

Comment: With intellisense: http://chpokk.apphb.com/
Another one without intellisense: http://csharpfiddle.com

Answer (score 8):

What about ".NET jsFiddle" ???

http://dotnetfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go with CodeMirror, which is the only that I know that has Auto Complete.

You can check a demo here: http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html.

And it's open source and actively developed, so, you can always contribute with improvements: https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror.

Comment: codemirror appears to only be javascript

Answer (score 0):

try this one (has autocomplete)

http://www.coderun.com/ide/

https://compilr.com  (Not sure about autocomplete )