# bootstrap opacity becomes white at the lower part

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a form inside the boostrap modal, when I click submit button I check for any invalid input/s and prompt the validation error message, the problem is when all the fields are empty then click the submit button , I'm able to show error message for each field but the background of the bootstrap modal becomes white at the lower part. Please see the image below.
[image]

Comment: Could you post the code or a fiddle?

Comment: i'm using asp.net mvc, is there a site to code that?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873367/is-there-an-asp-net-fiddle