# Adding Checkboxes to a GridView in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am trying to add a column of checkboxes to my grid view so that I can export only selected rows to Excel(current it exports the whole grid). I am using ASP.Net and C# and I am new to both languages. When I add a the checkbox column it displays with a checkbox in each row.It works until I link the master page to the aspx page and then the column appears but only one check box appears. The checkbox also does not appear in any row but half way down the page. Does anyone know how I can fix this or another way to select multiple rows from a data grid to export(the checkbox method is preferable)? Any help greatly appreciated.

The following is my ASP.Net Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false"      AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Shipment.aspx.cs"    Inherits="CertificateApplication.Shipment" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"%>



<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent" runat="server">
<h1 style="color:white;">Shipment Details</h1>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="container-fluid" ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <fieldset style="margin-right:20px;" >
            <!--Panel containing a grid view of data from the database. Not all data is selected, only the data required for the excel document-->
                <asp:Panel ID="DataGrid" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal" style="z-index:-1; margin-right: 248px;" Height="800px" Width="1206px">           
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceCertificate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CertificateDBConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductDetails]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="CertificateNumber" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCertificate" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="320px" Width="1327px" Font-Size="Small" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CertificateNumber" HeaderText=" Certificate No." ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CertificateNumber" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDescription" HeaderText="Name of Product   " SortExpression="ProductDescription" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NetWeight" HeaderText="Weight" SortExpression="NetWeight" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NoPackages" HeaderText= Number of  packages" SortExpression="NoPackages" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns
            </asp:GridView>
             </asp:Panel>
            <!--Buttons to export the data to excel -->
            <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" style=" left: 201px; top: 807px; position: absolute; width: 261px; height: 38px;" OnClick="btnExport_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnExportSelected" runat="server" Text="Export Selected Record to Excel" style=" left: 496px; top: 808px; position: absolute; width: 494px; height: 38px;" OnClick="btnExportSelected_Click"/>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- /.container-fluid-->
<!-- /.content-wrapper-->
<!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
<a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
</a>
```

The following is my C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace CertificateApplication
{
public partial class Shipment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
           server control at run time. */
    }

   protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",       string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Certificates.xls"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();

    }

}
```

}

I can provide my Master Code if needed! Thanks

Comment: if it shows fine without masterpage but not with masterpage, that's a css issue!. try it in chrom-> dev tools

Comment: I could not find what was causing it in the css file. I think my knowledge of coding isn't good enough to spot what is causing the checkbox to change. Do you know what i might be looking for or if post the css code here might you be able to identify the section affecting the checkbox ?

Comment: upload yr code somewhere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873367/is-there-an-asp-net-fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough points to ask a clarifying question, so I'll provide a possible answer. Check the master file and make sure there are no conflicting names like "CheckBox1". Are there *any* checkboxes on the master page? I would also be suspicious about which checkbox you are seeing - is it really from the Shipment page? Right-click inspect element on that checkbox, or view page source to get a better idea what was actually rendered. You may need to try `clientIDMode="static"` to help figure out whats happening.